# Find Exact Co-ordinate of view on Android screen

Tags: android, view, android-coordinatorlayout

It seems very simple but somehow I am not able to figure out how to find left(x) and top(y) coordinate of  view I tried almost every answer everyone gives zero.

Here is xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout     
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<include layout="@layout/include_list_viewpager" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer_view" />
```

include_list_viewpager.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout       
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/main_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/et_inputSearch"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/abc_action_bar_stacked_max_height"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/tiny_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/tiny_margin"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/tiny_margin"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_text_rounded_with_background_register"
        android:completionThreshold="1"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_search_black_24dp"
        android:drawablePadding="@dimen/default_margin"
        android:hint="@string/msg_hint_search_text_box"
        android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
        android:inputType="textCapSentences|textAutoCorrect"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/horizontal_margin"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryText"
        android:textColorHint="@color/divider"
        android:textSize="@dimen/info_text_heading" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/btn_filter"
            style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/frame_filter"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_text_filter"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_filter"
                    android:drawablePadding="@dimen/tiny_margin"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/txt_filter"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textColor="@color/white" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_filter"
                    android:layout_width="15dp"
                    android:layout_height="15dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="top|left"
                    android:background="@drawable/badge_filter_fab"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="10sp"
                    android:visibility="gone" />
            </FrameLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="1px"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@color/white" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/btn_sort"
            style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_sort"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_swap_vert_white_24dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/txt_sort"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="@color/white" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_sort_by"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:gravity="bottom"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/tiny_margin"
                android:text="@string/text_default"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="10sp" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:name="in.workindia.nileshdungarwal.workindiaandroid.fragments.FragJobAllList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_job_list" />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fl_bottom_container"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/default_margin"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/default_margin">

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="onFabClick"
        app:borderWidth="0dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_on_float"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:elevation="12dp"
        android:text="NEW"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
</FrameLayout>
```

```
**Code snippet to find out co-ordinate**
private void showUseSearch() {

    View etSearchTextList = findViewById(R.id.et_inputSearch);
    int[] tableLayoutCorners = new int[2];

    Rect myViewRect = new Rect();
    etSearchTextList.getGlobalVisibleRect(myViewRect);
    float x = myViewRect.left;
    float y = myViewRect.top;

    etSearchTextList.getLocationInWindow(tableLayoutCorners);

    Log.i(TAG, x+","+y+"-"+tableLayoutCorners[0] + "-" + tableLayoutCorners[1] + ",showUseSearch: " + etSearchTextList.getX() + "," + etSearchTextList.getY() + "-" + etSearchTextList.getPivotX() + "-" + etSearchTextList.getPivotY());
    }
```

Comment: if you will simply call yourlayout.getX() and yourlayout.getY() it will give you the top left point itself

Comment: Remember, that the view must be laid out. So you cannot do that inside ie. `Activity`'s `onCreate` method, unless you use [`ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener.html).

Answer (score 1):

If you will try to get position before rendering the UI completely you will get it zero. You could use the treeObserver listener to get the x and y after binding the UI. here you go :

```
view.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
    new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            // Layout has happened here.
            int x = (int)view.getX();// returns float
            int y = (int)view.getY();

            // Don't forget to remove your listener when you are done with it.
            view.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Actually, that was the case , My method was trying to fetch before even render so If I am calling from  public void onGlobalLayout() all are working perfectly.

Comment: yes, and to get the top left x y we don't need to take RECT or something. getx gety will give itself

Comment: @LokeshTiwari : Sorry something went wrong during edit! you can edit again to reflect